# GHUB Lua - Slow Mouse Movement Function

Tags: lua, mousemove, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to create a local function in Lua (GHUB) to move the mouse to a specific coordiinates on the screen.
However the pointer moves suddenly at the end of the function call ... and does not even go to the right position.
Also .. is there anyway I can debug Lua ... in GHUB is practically impossible from what I see. Not even syntax errors.

Thank you!

```
local function MouseMoveToSlower(x, y, speed)
    current_x, current_y = GetMousePosition()
    distance = math.sqrt((x - current_x)^2 + (y - current_y)^2)
    steps = math.floor(distance / speed)

    for i = 1, steps do
        new_x = current_x + (x - current_x) * i / steps
        new_y = current_y + (y - current_y) * i / steps
        MoveMouseRelative(new_x - current_x, new_y - current_y)
        Sleep(math.random(102,125))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`MoveMouseRelative` expects distance in `1 pixel` units  (screen width = 1920 units)
`GetMousePosition` returns distance in `(screen_size)/64K` units  (screen width = 65536 units)
You should convert values correctly.

Comment: Hello, It seems you send me to the right track. However I am still missing something. My monitor resolution is 2560x1440. I tried to convert it  using this, but it moves too much. I used 1280x720 as conversion and is almost ok, but depending on the starting position is goes slighly different. I dont belive is from the rounding .. it may be. Ist there anything else I am missing ? Thank you! https://pastebin.com/ereb6XVe

Comment: You should recalculate the remaining distance on every step.

Comment: Thnaks! I thought about that and will clearly help - I willl.
Out of curiositywhy is needed ?

Comment: `MoveMouseRelative` is unexact, Windows "mouse acceleration" feature determines the real number of pixels, it is often different from the argument of `MoveMouseRelative`.